# Partitioning using a substring of the s3 path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

We have a s3 bucket which has files in the following format:

`6ugdasznp56o_2020-09-04T140000_6081c358e0417bdd81284b0cf7a6b321_2853a9.csv.gz`

Is it possible to define a `storage.location.template` as follows:

`6ugdasznp56o_${year}-${month}-${date}T${hour}0000_6081c358e0417bdd81284b0cf7a6b321_2853a9.csv.gz`

to partition my files in this s3 bucket?

Comment: What do you mean, by "parition"? Like renaming your objects?

Comment: No. So we can partition the data if its stored in file path is as follows:

s3://<bucket name>/year/month/date/<file>

will be partitioned using year, month and date when crawled by AWS glue crawler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitioning can't happen on a file level but only on a folder structure, see also [Table Location in Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-location-format.html):

> Do not use any of the following items for specifying the `LOCATION` for your data.
>
> - Do not use filenames, underscores, wildcards, or glob patterns for specifying file locations.

Examples that **won't** work:

```
...
s3://path_to_bucket/mySpecialFile.dat
s3://bucketname/prefix/filename.csv
...
```